# Where do I find start in gradlew in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, runtimeexception, minecraft-forge

```
package speedychris2.Cheerio;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;

@Mod(modid = "Mod", name = "Mod", version = "1.0")
public class Cheerio {

}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:59)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

When I click on `(GradleStart.java:59)` It brings up a window telling me that 59 is not a valid line number in gradlestart then prompts me to attach a source, which of course I don't know. This is in eclipse with Forge ModLoader for Minecraft. I was following [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ULz-oCUbEg&list=UUSwwxl2lWJcbGOGQ_d04v2Q&index=32) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLXOTFF6BEI&index=31&list=UUSwwxl2lWJcbGOGQ_d04v2Q), and it gave me an error.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to __present clear problem statements__ - What's the _expected behaviour_, _specific error or unexpected behaviour you're getting_, and a ___reproducible example___? Please take a __[tour]__. Also see a [__Minimal__, __Complete__, and __Verifiable__ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [__Short__, __Self Contained__, Correct (__Compilable__) example](http://sscce.org/). Also, what's the version of Minecraft Forge you're using?

Comment: Are you sure you added AND implemented forge into your used libraries?